# Using re.sub only on those substrings in a string having length greater than 11 in python

Tags: python, regex

```
list_1=["TP","MP","TS"]

list_2=["RTS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPR13TS0002",
        "RTS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPS19TS0332"]
```

I am trying to look for elements of list_1 in substrings of elements of list_2 and replace them as follows:

For TS,
output should be

```
list_2=["RTS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPR13 TS",
        "RTS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPS19 TS"]
```

Insert space left of TS and remove anything right of it.

Instead of this, I am getting output as:

```
list_2=["R TS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPR13 TS",
        "R TS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPS19 TS"]
```

I am facing problem as it will also do same thing for RTS substring.I only want to perform operation for substrings having length greater than 10.

My list comprehension + regular expression is as below:

```
  updated_list=[ re.sub(r'(' +  '|'.join(list_1) + ')\S+', 
                 r' \1', i)for i in list_2]
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my improvement may be insufficient.

Comment: Your question is not correctly formatted.

Comment: Do you always have digits after a `list_1` element that you want to replace? If so, change the pattern to `r'(' +  '|'.join(list_1) + ')\d+'`.

Comment: that `r` in `r'('` seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

A not very efficient solution:

```
import re
str = "RTS:Id The package is delivered to TEMPR13TS0002"
pattern = re.compile('\w{11,}')
print pattern.sub(lambda m:re.sub("TS.*", " TS", m.group(0)), str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't suited for checking string lengths.

You could either alter `list_1` to handle the difference between `RTS:Id` and `13TS00` or use other Python functions to search, check and replace the strings.

ie. only match when TS is followed by a number
`list_1=["TP","MP","TS\d"]`